# getfacl returns rwx, but I have a "permission denied" when trying to access the said folder

Tags: rsync, acl

I'm trying to execute a script from Server A with user "vbackup" to copy some files from server B to server A.
On server A, I did

```
setfacl -Rdm user:vbackup:rwx /var/atlassian/
```

On server B, I run this command :

```
rsync -azh "vbackup@serverA:/var/atlassian" "/tmp/jira_datas"
```

For most of the files and folders it works, but for some files/folders I get

> rsync: opendir "/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/data/attachments/REF/10000/REF-462" failed: Permission denied (13)

Running `getfacl var/atlassian/application-data/jira/data/attachments/REF/10000/REF-462` returns this

[image]

I don't understand why I get the permission denied on some folders when it works with other folders with the same rights. Can anyone explain? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to show a picture if you copy/paste the output of the command into your question and format it as a code block by clicking on '{}'.

Comment: If I could I would, but it's a VM from which I can't copy/paste...

Comment: Can you post the result of `ls -ld /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/data/attachments/REF/10000/REF-462`?

Comment: Sure!

`drwxr-x---+ 2 jira jira 4096 juil.  9 15:53 /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/data/attachments/REF/10000/REF-462`   

For some reasons the path is colored in blue

Comment: It's blue because it is a directory.

Comment: For now I've given chmod 777 on these files and it solved the problem, but I'd like to understand...